# Calculate the difference between two dates in smarty 3 template prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, smarty3

I have to calculate a sale end time relative to today,

I have the sale end time variable in this format `{%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S}` **e.g.:`(31/07/2016 18:27:58)`**.

What I'm trying to do is to show `ends: 8 days 06:10:29`.
I can't use php code in the template because I'm using smarty 3 and I'm not an expert in smarty.

Comment: And the returned value should be counting down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your date1 and date2 values

```
{assign var="date1" value= $smarty.now}
{assign var="date2" value= $smarty.now+20*24*60*60}

{assign var="dateDiff" value=$date2 - $date1}

{$dateDiff|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}
```

Comment: Logic shouldn't be in views, only loops and echoes. Otherwise it totally defeats the view templating.The real answer is to calculate the correct output in PHP first before sending that data to Smarty.

Comment: as per the question, it was looking for an answer for Smarty template

Comment: Indeed, but we should educate people to code to best practices.

Comment: totally agreed.